# Firefox extension - panel elements onclick getting overwritten

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, add-on

I am trying to assign an onclick event to a dynamically created panel element:

```
for(var c = 0; c < data.length; c++) {
    var user = data[c];
    document.querySelector('#userList').innerHTML += '<li class="user" id="button-login-' + c + '"><img src="user.png" /><span>' + user.username + '</span></li>';
    document.querySelector('#button-login-' + c).onclick = function() {
        self.port.emit('button', {
            'action': 'login',
            'data': {
                'username': user.username
            }
        });
    };
}
```

But it seems that the first onclick events being overwritten by the last one...
Any help?

In the new code i tried this:

```
for(var c = 0; c < data.length; c++) {
    user = data[c];
    document.querySelector('#userList').innerHTML += '<li class="user" id="button-login-' + c + '"><img src="user.png" /><span>' + user.username + '</span></li>';
    document.querySelector('#button-login-' + c).onclick = function() {
        self.port.emit('button', {
            'action': 'login',
            'data': {
                'username': user.username
            }
        });
    };
}
```

and this:

```
for(var c = 0; c < data.length; c++) {
    let user = data[c];
    document.querySelector('#userList').innerHTML += '<li class="user" id="button-login-' + c + '"><img src="user.png" /><span>' + user.username + '</span></li>';
    document.querySelector('#button-login-' + c).onclick = function() {
        self.port.emit('button', {
            'action': 'login',
            'data': {
                'username': user.username
            }
        });
    };
}
```

the buttons don't work...

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/) for guidance.

Comment: This is because your onclick handler is a closure. All the onclick event handlers would point to the last user object . See http://britseyeview.com/software/articles/closures.html.
Welcome to javascript :)

Comment: @Kashif Make that a proper answer and get an upvote ;)

Comment: @nmaier Made my comment an answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because of the way closures work in Javascript, not something specific to sdk or extensions.

See "[Creating closures in loops: A common mistake](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake)" for a general solution to your problem.

For a simpler solution change

```
var user = data[c];
```

to

```
let user = data[c];
```

Comment: the problem is still there, the buttons can't be clicked... the onclick event doesn't occur